# Show that $D =\{ x + y \mid x \in (0,1) ,y \in [1,2) \}$ is open or closed

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidian metric $|x-y|$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show with arguments that the set $D =\{ x + y \mid x \in (0,1) ,y \in [1,2) \}$ is open or closed.

As a definition for open/closed I have:

Definition of **open**:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $U \subseteq X$. The set $U$ is called open set if: for every $U$ there exists some $\epsilon > 0 $ such that $B_\epsilon (x) \subseteq U$.

Definition of **closed**:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $F \subseteq X$. The set $F$ is called closed if $X\setminus F$ is called open.

Actually I do not have a real idea how to start yet. First I would draw the graph, but here I do not know where to start...

I would really appreciate your answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, show that if $U$ is open and $X$ is any set then $U+X$ is open.

Comment: How would you do that. Please share a hint!

Comment: $$U+X = \bigcup_{x\in X} \left(U+\{x\}\right)$$ and $U+\{x\}$ is open for any $x$

Comment: Would you take $(1,3)$ as U?

Comment: No, $U=(0,1)$ and $X=[1,2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Show your set is equal to $(1,3)$, and then use what you know about what kinds of intervals are open and what kinds of intervals are closed.

Further hint: Using the inequalities on $x$ and $y$, you can show your set is contained in $(1,3)$. To show $(1,3)$ is contained in your set, for $z \in (1,3)$  write $z = 3 - \epsilon$ where $0 < \epsilon < 2$ and consider $z = (1 - \epsilon/2) + (2 - \epsilon/2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much @user2566092 for your answer! What is the graph for this set? How did you get the intervall $(1,3)$?